# Creating a Delete Button Using CakePHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, button, cakephp-2.0

I want to create a delete button using bootstrap,

currently I have this:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger remover" data-refid="3" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remover">
    <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
</a>
```

But I want my 'action' => 'delete', $variable['']['']

any Idea how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like the [delete link example in the doc ?](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink)

Comment: That's different, I don't wanna use a text in my button, I wanna use other icon, in the examples from cakephp description I can chance one class, in my case "btn btn-danger remover", but how can I add the part "<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>" ?

Comment: Just put it as the text value and add "escape => false" in the option array.